# Why is drawing a large matrix of random numbers outside a threaded loop faster than drawing a column at a time inside the loop?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I have to run some operation `do_stuff` on a lot of random numbers.  I initially wrote code that looks something like this:

```
X = randn( 3, 1000000 )
Y = Vector{Float64}( undef, 1000000 )
@threads for n in 1:size( X, 2 )
    Y[n] = do_stuff( X[:,n] )
end
```

I thought I'd make the random number draws parallel too like so:

```
Y = Vector{Float64}( undef, 1000000 )
@threads for n in 1:size( X, 2 )
    X = randn( 3 )
    Y[n] = do_stuff( X )
end
```

I expected this to be faster because `randn` is being called in parallel but it's actually about 20% slower.  And this is actually about 40-50% slower:

```
X = Vector{Float64}( undef, 3, 1000000 )
Y = Vector{Float64}( undef, 1000000 )
@threads for n in 1:size( X, 2 )
    X[:,n] = randn( 3 )
    Y[n] = do_stuff( X[:,n] )
end
```

Why is this so?

Comment: is this just benchmarking in the global scope? If not, can you put this into a function?

Comment: @OscarSmith This is in a function.  I just didn't include the `function ... end` lines.

Answer (score 3):

Generating many random numbers at a time can indeed be efficient, but you have more problems here. You are allocating an enormous number of temporary arrays here:

```
X[:,n] = randn( 3 )
Y[n] = do_stuff( X[:,n] )
```

The call `randn(3)` in the first line allocates a new array for each iteration, and the call `X[:, n]` creates a copy, too (the `X[:, n]` in the first line isn't actually a slice, so does not allocate.) Benchmark:

```
function foo!(X, Y)
    Threads.@threads for n in axes(X, 2)  # don't use 1:size, use axes
        X[:, n] = randn(3)
        Y[n] = maximum(X[:,n])
    end
    return Y
end

X = Matrix{Float64}( undef, 3, 10000 );
Y = Vector{Float64}( undef, 10000 );
julia> @btime foo!($X, $Y);
  260.600 μs (20048 allocations: 1.53 MiB)
```

Let's fix the two issues I mentioned:

```
function bar!(X, Y)
    Threads.@threads for n in axes(X, 2)
        X[:, n] .= randn.()  # makes a separate number for each row in X
        Y[n] = maximum(@view X[:, n])
    end
    return Y
end
```

`X[:, n] .= randn.()` generates the random numbers in-place, without any temporary. And here: `Y[n] = maximum(@view X[:, n])` the `@view` macro creates a view instead of a copy.

New benchmark:

```
julia> @btime baz!($X, $Y);
  61.700 μs (48 allocations: 5.28 KiB)
```

Dramatically fewer allocations, and they are all due to the multithreading, single-threaded there should be zero allocations.

Let's compare to generating all random numbers in a single go:

```
function foo!(Y)
    # All rands in one go, but still using slices
    X = randn(3, length(Y))
    Threads.@threads for n in axes(X, 2)
        Y[n] = maximum(X[:,n])
    end
    return Y
end

function bar!(Y)
    # All rands in one go, but using views
    X = randn(3, length(Y))
    Threads.@threads for n in axes(X, 2)
        Y[n] = maximum(@view X[:,n])
    end
    return Y
end

julia> @btime foo!($Y);
  168.700 μs (10048 allocations: 1020.89 KiB)

julia> @btime bar!($Y);
  98.600 μs (48 allocations: 239.64 KiB)
```

As you can see, `foo!(Y)` is faster than `foo!(X, Y)`, but much slower than `bar!(X, Y)`. And even when you use views, `bar!(Y)` is slower than `bar!(X, Y)`.

In other words, it is not as clear-cut that generating all rands at once is always faster. In stead, inspect your code, and look for instances of needless creation of temporary arrays. That is a performance red-flag.

Comment: Shouldn't the number of threads be specified when benchmarking threaded code (BTW same question applies to the OP)? I mean, it would be interesting to know how the speedup changes vs. the # of threads

Comment: I dunno.The number of threads are equal between the different test cases at least. The point of the answer is anyway not to provide a definitive solution, but to point out general performance issues in the OP, and show that it's not *always* best to pre-generate all rands.

Comment: Thank you.  There's not actually a reason to store X.  Is there some way to do the draws in threads but not allocate an X with as many columns as Y has elements?  How do you pre-allocate for a thread so you're not allocating for X each loop?

Comment: It depends a bit. Is 3 a number that can be hard-coded into your function, or is it a dynamic parameter? Or could it be a static parameter. Hard-coded, you could do `x = ntuple(_->randn(), 3)`, for example, if `do_stuff` accepts a tuple. Or use an `SVector`: `x = randn(SVector{3, eltype(Y)})`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the total allocation is the same, doing it in one go is expected to be faster.

```
julia> function f()
           randn(3, 1000000)
       end

julia> function g()
           for _ in 1000000
               randn(3)
           end
       end

julia> @benchmark f()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 967 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  4.959 ms …   7.275 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 3.81%
 Time  (median):     5.205 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   5.160 ms ± 182.650 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.23% ± 2.19%

     ▁▆█▇▄▂                 ▂▄▆▅▅▁
  ▂▃▇██████▆▅▅▃▃▃▃▃▁▁▂▂▁▃▃▆▇██████▇▆▅▃▃▂▂▂▂▃▁▁▁▂▂▁▁▁▂▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▂ ▄
  4.96 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        5.57 ms <

 Memory estimate: 22.89 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.

julia> @benchmark g()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 117 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  41.446 ms …  47.920 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 3.53% … 2.96%
 Time  (median):     43.109 ms               ┊ GC (median):    6.75%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   42.849 ms ± 871.271 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  5.94% ± 1.44%

                     ▁█▆
  ▃▄▇▆▂▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▅███▅▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂ ▂
  41.4 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         46.4 ms <

 Memory estimate: 76.29 MiB, allocs estimate: 1000000.
```

I doubt parallel would help you beat `f()` in general cuz you might just be memory bandwidth bounded.